# Gose Question for the Gosers (too much salt)

Tags: extract, adjunct

So I found a recipe for gose on a site, and thought it looked interesting.  However, I am bound to extract at the moment, as my mash tun is under repair.  I converted to extract, but long story short, I think I may have over-salted it.  The recipe I found was for 10gal, and I made 5.  I adjusted everything but the salt (but did adjust the salt at the last minute, thinking it might just be too much).

-3.3 lbs pale LME

-3.3 lbs bavarian wheat LME (I think my color may be off as well)

-2 lbs milled acid malt steeped for 30 min pre-boil at 160

-1oz styrian goldings 60 min (stepped this up from 0.5 oz in the recipe as I was doing a partial-volume boil)

-1 oz ground coriander (15 min - may have gone overboard on this as well)

-salt (here's where my recollection gets hazy.  I either did 25 g or 30 g (don't ask why I used metric, it was on the original 10 gal recipe), which is between .88oz and 1.05oz)

-1 lb pureed fresh figs (beer is for my brother who loves figs...may try them in the secondary as well if they ferment out)

-1 vial WL kolsch yeast pitched at ~72 deg after dilution to 5.2 gallons

-OG of 1.052

Obviously I won't know until its done fermenting and I give it a try.  However, assuming it is a salty mess, could I brew another 5 gallons and dilute?  If I did, I might secondary this first salt-lick batch with more figs, as I'm guessing the ones I put in pre-fermentation will get vaporized by those kolschies anyway.

The other risk is, I have never had this style before, and might simply effing hate it, in which case, I would then have 10 gallons of beer I don't particularly like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this byo article [link](http://www.byo.com/stories/beer-styles/article/indices/11-beer-styles/1022-leipziger-gose-style-profile) your whithin tolerance. The author says he can tolerate 1/3 cup in 5 gallons. 
I would definitely wait and see before brewing 5 more gallons. Even if you decide to do so later you might want to tweak sourness, spice etc for blending,